# Separator after the last item imploded PHP

Tags: php

I would like to know how can i make my implode() looks like

```
name1, name2, name3,
```

this is my code

```
if (!empty($datas)) {
  echo implode('<i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:green;font-size:20px;margin-bottom: 0px !important;float:right;" ></i><br> ', $datas);;
}
```

basically i want to add the separator to the last item too

Comment: Append an empty entry to `$datas`?

Comment: i cant add an empty entry i tried and didnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

Could try this

```
$output = join("seperator",implode(.....));
```

Or crazy thought. Implode, then manually add it in:

```
if (!empty($datas)) {
  $imploded = implode('<i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:green;font-size:20px;margin-bottom: 0px !important;float:right;" ></i><br> ', $datas);
  $imploded .= '<i class="fas fa-check-circle" style="color:green;font-size:20px;margin-bottom: 0px !important;float:right;" ></i><br>'
}
```

Comment: i cloud use 
if (!empty($datas)) {echo implode('', $data)."icon" and get the same result but that affects other data showed on my page, thats why i was asking for a method to add the separator inside the implode function

Comment: There isn't since implode() only accepts two arguments. Appending that to the end of your implode should not affect anything.. it would do the same as you're suggesting, adding the separator to the end of the array being imploded.

Answer (score 0):

Here are three examples that might help you.

```
$separator = '[separator]';
$d1 = ['Harry', 'Diana', 'Marvel'];
echo implode($separator, $d1) . "\n";

$d2 = ['Harry', 'Diana', 'Marvel', ''];
echo implode($separator, $d2) . "\n";

$d3 = ['', 'Harry', 'Diana', 'Marvel', ''];
echo implode($separator, $d3) . "\n";
```

Here is the output

```
Harry[separator]Diana[separator]Marvel
Harry[separator]Diana[separator]Marvel[separator]
[separator]Harry[separator]Diana[separator]Marvel[separator]
```

Comment: This solution cant help me because i am guetting data from a database, and thoes data are dyanmique changes depending on the viewed page

Comment: Then please enhance your question so we understand all these details and can help you.

Comment: i have a page that displays cars brand and each one with included and not included features, like this Exemple
Audi A3
cd "green logo"
bluetooth "green logo"
wifi "red logo"

all thoes options are puled from the database
now i get the red and green icons except the last one thats why i was asking how can i add the separator to the last item because i am using the icons as separator

Comment: Add it to the original question. Don't put it in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');
$comma_separated = implode(",", $array);
$comma_separated .= ',';
```

Comment: data are coming from database so i cant aply this solution :/

Answer (score 0):

It isn't reliable to use `implode()` then unconditionally append a trailing delimiter for cases where an array might be empty.

If you are seeking a functional-style approach, then `array_reduce()` can most directly iterate your values as a delimited string.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/TQMCC))

```
$array  = ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'];
$separator = ', ';

echo array_reduce(
         $array,
         fn($text, $value) => "$text$value$separator"
     );
```

Output:

```
name1, name2, name3,
```

There's nothing wrong with performing the same concatenation with a `foreach()` loop,     it just requires a globally scoped variable to be declared versus `array_reduce()`'s function-scoped `$text` variable.